# Add new chart in blank PPTX using OpenXML/PresentationML

Tags: c#, charts, openxml, presentationml

I am using OpenXML to generate new presentation from the scratch. Here i want to add new chart to the presentation with my custom data. Though I am able to update existing chart, i am not able to create new one.

Please guide me..